# Finding if a reversed string has a match in a list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, reverse

I am learning Python, one month in and I am struggling with the following problem:

An ice cream shop has a list of flavors:

FLAVORS = [
"Banana",
"Chocolate",
"Lemon",
"Pistachio",
"Raspberry",
"Strawberry",
"Vanilla",
]

They want to build a list of all the alternatives of a 2 balls flavoured ice creams.
The flavours cannot be repeated:
ie. Chocolate Banana cannot be listed as Banana Chocolate is already in the list.
I have to print the list.

Here's my code:

```
result = []
sub_result = ""

for ice in FLAVORS:
       for other_ice in FLAVORS:
            
            if ice == other_ice:
                continue
                
            sub_result = ice + ", " + other_ice

            if reversed(sub_result) in result:
                continue
        
            result.append(sub_result)
        
print ('\n'.join([item for item in result ])) '''
```

I cannot get the script to bypass the reversed iteration of the favours.

Comment: You are concattenatting strings, if you reverse `'Ban, Schok'` you get `'kohcS ,naB'`... debug your code using prints! Collect 2 flavors in a list and reverse the list. Use `', '.join(yourflavorlist)` for printing. Reversing `["Schok","Ban"]` will give you `["Ban","Schok"]`

Comment: Thank you Patrick. I will try my script with your recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `reversed` reverses an iterable. It returns an iterator, *not* a string! And you don't want to reverse the string, because that would give you things like `'nomeL ,etalocohC'`.

Secondly, make use of the fact that you already know which items you already have in the reverse order!

```
FLAVORS = [ "Banana", "Chocolate", "Lemon", "Pistachio", "Raspberry", "Strawberry", "Vanilla"]

result = []

for i, ice in enumerate(FLAVORS):
       for other_ice in FLAVORS[i + 1:]:
            result.append(f'{first_flavor} {second_flavor}')
        
print('\n'.join(result))
```

Comment: Lovely and crisp, thank you for reminding me that I can use index!

Answer (score 0):

Using `sub_result = ice + ", " + other_ice` makes `sub_result` a string. For example, for `Banana` and `Chocolate`, you get `'Banana, Chocolate'`. You need `('Banana', 'Chocolate')`.

You need to use a `tuple` or `list` instead:

```
sub_result = tuple(reversed((ice, other_ice)))
```

Notice the cast to `tuple` - This is because `reversed` returns an object, not the reverse of the input. The object has to interpreted as the required type.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will try to implement this within my code and try it out. Jasmijn proposed a simpler solution than my code but I still need to get the reflexes right. Why didn't I use index I don't know! :)

Comment: In this case there is no need for `reversed`. You can simply check against `(other_ice, ice)` instead.